# fingertip detection from depth Image using kinect (c# and wpf)

Tags: c#, wpf, detection, kinect, depth

I'm making a project for my university, I'm working with kinect and i want to detect the finger tips using microsoft sdk.I made depth segmentation based on the closest object and player so i now have only the hand part in my image. But I have no idea what to do next. I'm trying to get the hand's boundary but not finding the method to do it.
so can anyone help me and suggest some usefull ways or ideas to do that.
I am using c# and wpf
It will be great if anyone can provide a sample code. I only want to detect the index finger and the thumb.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Btw about finding the boundaries. Think about this.
Kinect gives you position of your hand. Your hand is on some Z position. It`s the distance from the Kinect device. Now every pixel (from depth stream) of your hand is almoust on the same Z position as the join of your hand. Your boundarie will be an pixel that is much more in background than your hand. This way you can get boundaries in every direction for your hand. You just need to analyze pixel data
Hope it helped

Answer (score 0):

Try [this download](http://candescentnui.codeplex.com/releases/view/69916), it is Kinect finger detection, and get the "Recommended" download on the page, I have found the `.dll`s in it work well. Good Luck!

Comment: Thank you but it's made using openNI whereas I want to do it using the microsoft sdk and I have no experience using openNI. can you help me more to use these .dll s ? and what is the procedure to use ?

Comment: @MakramBg Ill work on them some in the next few days to help you

Comment: Thanks that's what I'll do but can you advice me where to start ?